# Products list with search field and selection field in wizard in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Can we get product list with search field and selection field in wizard with click of button?

```
return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'tree',
        'view_mode': 'tree',
        'res_model': 'product.product',
        'views': [(False, 'tree')],
        'name': 'Bulk Products',
        'target': 'new',
        }
```

It only shows product list without search and selection field.

Answer (score 0):

i assume your want to open wizard and in wizard you need product.product selection field to select product

to do that first you need to create wizard 
and in wizard .py file create field

```
product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="product")
```

and put this field in wizard's xml file in form view.

so the product list with search more option will appeared